# Making a self contained executable for mac

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have made a .net core console app in Visual Studio.  I want to package it now as an executable for both windows & mac.

I added the runtime section to project.json.

This is my projects.json based on what I saw here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/index#self-contained-application

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "AngleSharp": "0.9.9",
    "CsvHelper": "2.16.3",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},
    "osx.10.10-x64": {}
  }
}
```

This creates a folder in debug/release called `win10-x64` that includes an executable but there is no folder for osx.

Am I missing a dependency to target this OS?

Answer (score 10):

The answer was to publish it from the command line

```
dotnet publish -r osx.10.10-x64
```

Then the folder `/osx.10.10-x64/publish/` holds a file that can be run on a mac that has the SDK installed.

Comment: -r doesn't actually do much yet, I think it might use some settings if you've configured them per-platform or something. Eventually you'll be able to use it to bundle the runtime with your app into one binary for a specific platform but that capability wasn't ready for 1.0. I just used your command on a project I previously published for Windows/Linux and the only files it republished were PROJECTNAME.deps.json, PROJECTNAME.runtimeconfig.json, and web.config, and it did so in my existing bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish. The project DLL itself wasn't recompiled.

Comment: It seems to be working.  I got a file I could run on a mac

Answer (score -1):

.NET Core does not build executables directly. Though that is in the roadmap, last I checked (1.0.1) it doesn't do that yet. You will get a DLL file on compile which you can run by passing it in to the dotnet binary. Don't let the DLL extension fool you, it works on any supported platform.

As the other guy said you should do a publish to ensure all your app files are copied to the publishing folder so they're ready to bundle up, but the same DLL file is just copied there. I've taken the same publish results and run them on both Windows under IIS and Red Hat under Kestrel.